# Alias tcsh to python script then return result back to tcsh?

Tags: python, tcsh

I want to create a version of cd which will strip off a filename from a directory structure and then cd to that directory.

So for example if I put in the (tc)shell

```
cd /net/homes/me/myfile.jpg
```

it will strip off 'myfile.jpg' and cd to the directory structure. I tried this is my .cshrc:-

```
alias ccd '/net/homes/me/scripts/getDir.py'
```

Then my getDir.py file reads as:-

```
#! /usr/bin/python

import sys
import os

def get_dir():
    the_dir = sys.argv[1]
    dir_split = the_dir.split("/")
    dir_count = len(the_dir.split("/"))

    file_count = len(dir_split[dir_count-1])
    only_dirs = the_dir[:-file_count]
    #print only_dirs
    os.chdir(only_dirs)


get_dir()
```

This strips off the filename part of the dir structure fine (I can tell that from the print statement) but the chdir command doesn't seem to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a standard binary called `dirname` which does this for you, so you can just use...

```
alias ccd 'cd `dirname \!:1`'
```

> This works, can you explain the syntax?

Well, the `dirname \!:1` part means to run the `dirname` program with the first argument passed to the aliased command, and the backticks substitute the output from that program into the `cd` command.

Comment: @user2479153 See [this page](http://home.adelphi.edu/sbloch/class/archive/271/fall2005/notes/aliases.html) for some more examples.

Comment: Thanks that's great. Just for learning purposes, how would I get my Python script to return the stripped dir structure to tcsh? Any ideas?

Comment: @user2479153 Have the Python script `print` the stripped path to stdout, and substitute `dirname` for the path to your Python script.

Comment: @D_G Oh, and if you want to do it in Python, you could just use [`os.path.dirname()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname). A script like: `import sys,os; print os.path.dirname(sys.argv[1])` would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

chdir doesn't change the state of the calling shell.

You need to change your alias to be something like this ( not sure of the exact tcsh syntax ):

```
  alias ccd 'cd `getDir.py`'
```

Then your getDir script does nothing but print the correct path string ( no chdir needed )

Comment: I tried something like this but couldn't get this to work also. I get     cd: Too many arguments.
Somehow python is returning more than one argument?

Comment: @user2479153 This won't actually work, because the parameter is outside of the backticks, so it won't be passed to your script.